# UIView одновременно с cornerRadius и Shadow

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть кастомная UIView с лэйблами внутри.

Хочу сделать ей закругленные углы с легкой тенью как на картинке снизу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня не получается, могу сделать либо одно, либо другое.

Все из-за конфликтов clipToBounds / maskToBounds.

Как правильно поступить в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = false
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
```